# Magento 1: How to check image file is uploaded or not without using Global variable $_FILES()?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

Is there any way to check that image file is uploaded or not without use of $_FILES() ? in Magento 1.9.4.0

Comment: What is the context? Where is your image upload occurring, is this in the fronted or backend, is this a custom module? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: it is backend for image upload for custom module